# number of items in the second list that aren't in the first list in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Let's say my first list is:

`[{tenancyNumber:777,no:1}, {tenancyNumber:888,no:2}, {tenancyNumber:999,no:3}]`

And my second List is

`[{tenancyNumber:444,no:4}, {tenancyNumber:999,no:5}, {tenancyNumber:666,no:6}]`

So, if we compare by name in the two lists there are 2 objects in the second list which are not in the first list. How to find out this in Java?

**This is what i tried:**

```java
final Long newAccounts = endDateData.stream()
  .map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)
  .filter(startDateData.stream().map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)::equals)
  .count();
```

which is throwing an error

> [PredicateIncompatibleType] Predicate will always evaluate to false
>   because types Stream and Long are incompatible

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a lookup `Set` of tenancy numbers for easing in the filter while you iterate on the second list.

```
Set<Long> tenancies = startDateData.stream()
                                   .map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now the attempt you made can be fixed as;

```
final Long newAccounts = endDateData.stream()
                                    .map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)
                                    .filter(num -> !tenancies.contains(num)) // here
                                    .count();
```

---

To help you understand the error message that you were facing, consider the code

```
(end/start)DateData.stream().map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)
```

this would return a `Stream<Long>`, now what you ended up performing in your `filter` stage was to compare `Stream<Long>` to a `Long` value of tenancy number from another `Stream` as

```
startDateData.stream().map(TenancyHistory::getTenancyNumber)::equals
```

and hence the error message read this would evaluate always to `false`. Such that resulting value of your would always be `0`.